# A question about integer BMO 1984 Question 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is derived from BMO 1984 question 4.

Given an integer n, how many r (with r bigger than 0 less than 1) can make 2nr an integer?

I tried some values of n and from 1 to 9 there are 1,2,3,3,3,5,3,4,5 r that meet the requirement.

I find it hard to generalise it to n.(Maybe I have done something wrong?)

Could anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: what is $r$ here? is it just any real in $(0,1)$? If the latter, can't you just take any $r \in \{ k/(2n) \mid k = 1,...,2n-1 \}$? Clearly $0 < 2nr < 2n$ if $r \in (0,1)$, and this set of $r$-s gives all the integers $1, ..., 2n-1$. I must be confused...

Comment: @SamT I was wondering the same thing. As stated, the problem seems trivial. Maybe there is a condition missing?

Comment: Assuming that "BMO" here doesn't have the meaning I'm accustomed to, "bounded mean oscillation", I googled it and found "Bank of Montreal".

Comment: Yes Sam T r is any real number in (0,1). Could you please explain why I can take ∈{/(2)∣=1,...,2−1}? Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasBlass "British Mathematical Olympiad"

Comment: @SelinaWong How did you come up with the results $1,2,3,3,3,5,3,4,5$? For example, for $n=2$, what values of $r$ did you find that make $4r$ an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that the condition $0<r<1$ implies $0<2nr<2n$. Next observe that for any integer $m, 0 < m< 2n$, there is precisely one $r\in(0,1)$ with $m=2nr$ (namely, $r=m/2n$). Therefore the question is equivalent to the following question: for an integer $n$, how many integers $m$ satisfy $0 < m < 2n$. Clearly this is $2n-1$.

Comment: Thank you pwerth! Your answer seems logical. But I don't quite understand your second statement (beginning with next). Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @SelinaWong It might help to choose some values for $n$ and see what happens: when $n=1$, $r = \frac12$. When $n=2$, $r \in \{\frac14, \frac24, \frac34\}$. When $n=3$, $r \in \{\frac16, \frac26, \frac36, \frac46, \frac56\}$, and so on.

Comment: I got it! I thought I was supposed to find the number of factors of 2n but this is wrong. Thank you all!

Comment: Thanks Théophile!